# How to Import Specific Files Inside Node_Modules

Tags: npm, webpack, vue.js

Okay, so I am using webpack-simple for VueJS. I installed a theme called AdminLTE. I tried to import the bootstrap files inside it via the code below. When I run `npm run build`, the app searches inside the src folder but AdminLTE is inside node_modules folder.

Should I import just those files that I need, or should I import the whole folder. And How do I properly import those files?

**My main.js file**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

// import BootstrapCSS from 'admin-lte/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css'
// import BootstrapCSSTheme from 'admin-lte/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.min.css'
import 'admin-lte/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'admin-lte/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.min.css'


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**My Webpack Config**

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: './dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
         test: /\.css$/,
         use: ['style-loader','css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Comment: Just used tilde sign before admin lte because of any folder available under node_modules without @ sign you can access it by tilde sign example
```js
@import '~admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.min.css';
```
if @ sign available before folder then you can access it by @ sign example

```js
@import '@admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.min.css';
```

Answer (score 11):

You probably need to reference the directory using a relative path.

If your main.js is in /src, then use:

```
import '../node_modules/admin-lte/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css'
```